# How do I filter a pivot table for MTD, QTD, and YTD?

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table

I have a column full of specific date and time information, but I want use that data to filter my table to show only MTD, QTD, and YTD rows.

I can't upload an image of my table because of my work computer program, but I have the variable with the dates in the "report filter" field. The data in the column is given as an individual date and time, so that's all I can select when I try to filter it. There's too many option, and I need to be able to select simply QTD, MTD, or YTD dates. How can I do this? Apologies for the lack of imagery.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select any part of the Pivot table
2. Under the `Analyze` tab of the ribbon select `Insert Slicer` or `Insert Timeline` whichever you prefer
3. Filter the dataset based on the criteria you want.

This won't give you your select columns, but without seeing the way you're data is structured should be a good fix.

If you have the issue where the dates won't summarize by month you can create two new columns to summarize the data and create a table with the following columns:

```
Month # / Month Name
1         January 'you can use whatever naming convention you prefer (jan, etc.)
2         February
....
```

Then you want to use the `MONTH` function combined with a `VLOOKUP`. It should look like `=vlookup(month( [date cell reference]), [table you just made], 2, 0)` This will pull the month name. Then you can use the `YEAR` function to get the years. Then make sure the pivot table accounts to the adjusted range and pull those in instead of date. You can still use the slicer and timeline to filter out the dates, but it will be summarized based on these new labels.

Comment: Well any way that I filter the data, it lists out every single time and date in the whole column, and this is also what happens with a slicer. I'm looking to refine that data more and I'm not sure how to go about that

Comment: One possible way I found to do it is use the dates as a row label and create a custom date filter, I just don't know what sort of formula to put in to include only the past 30 days, or 90 days, or 365 days. I'm in excel 2003, is there a formula that would work there?

Comment: @hrc00 i adjusted the answer with a way to label things differently so it pulls through.

Comment: You can also use those month numbers to label quarters similar method with the month if you want that way.